# Dozer deep propery mapping with custom converter

Tags: mapping, dozer

I have deep property mapping in my application (from domain objects to DTO, and the reverse), similar to next example:

```
...

<field>
    <a>employee.id</a>
    <b>employeeId</a>
</field>

...
```

When Dozer converts Domain to DTO, it maps `employee.id` to `employeeId`, and that is ok.
When Dozer converts DTO to Domain, it maps `employeeId` to a new Employee instance with id=employeeId.

**I want to create some logic for this deep property mapping**, but i just can't figure out solution. I tried to implement `CustomConverter`(or extend `DozerConverter`) but Dozer passes me Integer type as source and destination class(and expect Integer as result).

**EDIT**:
More precisely, what i need is to map `employee` in Domain to `null` if `employeeId` in DTO is 0.

Is this possible?

Any advice?

**EDIT ACCORDING TO ANSWERS**:
I solve problem with field-level custom converter. Instead of earlier, above mentioned, mapping, now i have something like this...

```
...

<field custom-converter="ManyToOneIdMapper" custom-converter-param="id">
    <a>employee</a>
    <b>employeeId</b>
</field>

...
```

In ManyToOneIdMapper i have...

```
public class ManyToOneIdMapper implements ConfigurableCustomConverter{

//...
//parameter field declaration, setParameter and getParameter implementations etc.
//...

public Object convert(Object existingDestinationFieldValue, Object sourceFieldValue, 
        Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {
    try {

        if(sourceClass.equals(Integer.class)){
            Integer src=(Integer)sourceFieldValue;

            if(src==null || src==0)
                return null;

            String setterName=formatMethodName("set", getParameter());
            Method setterMethod=destinationClass.getMethod(setterName, Integer.class);
            Object instance=destinationClass.newInstance();

            setterMethod.invoke(instance, src);

            return instance;
        }else{    
            if(sourceFieldValue==null)
                return 0;

            String getterName=formatMethodName("get", getParameter());
            Method getterMethod=sourceClass.getMethod(getterName);
            Object instance=getterMethod.invoke(sourceFieldValue);

            return instance;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){}
    return null;
}

/**
 * @return - method name (most often setter or getter)  according to fieldName.
 * For example formatMethodName("get", "id") returns "getId"
 */
protected String formatMethodName(String methodPrefix, String fieldName){
    String trimmedFieldName=fieldName.trim();
    String firstLetter=String.valueOf(trimmedFieldName.charAt(0));
    String capitalizedFirstLetter=firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    String methodName=methodPrefix+""+capitalizedFirstLetter+""+fieldName.substring(1);

    return methodName;
}
```

`custom-converter-param` is just name of id-field in Domain object. With that name, i just call setter or getter method in my converter. Probably, it is not the happiest solution, but it works for my problem scenario.

Comment: For the DTO->Domain case are you wanting to perform a lookup of an Employee with that ID which is already persisted in a database?

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki - Not exactly. I just want to set Domain.employee to null if DTO.employeeId is 0 or less. I changed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `CustomConverter` to map the parent object, for example:

Domain

```
class PersonA {
    ...
    int employeeId;
    ...
}
```

DTO

```
class PersonB {
    ...
    Employee employee;
    ...
}

class Employee {
    ...
    int id;
    ...
}
```

You want to map the two classes `PersonA` and `PersonB` using a `CustomConverter`, this will let you construct them what ever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a `CustomConverter` (per the other answer), or use a `DozerEventListener` to set the employee object back to null after the mapping has finished, if the ID is 0.

Comment: example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) (author here). It will intelligently map the scenario you describe without requiring any configuration or custom converters. Considering the model:

```
class Person {
  Employee employee;
}

class Employee {
  int id;
}

class PersonDTO {
  int employeeId;
}
```

Mapping is simple:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
PersonDTO personDTO = modelMapper.map(person, PersonDTO.class);
```

To conditionally map `Person.employee` when `PersonDTO.employeeId` is not zero, we simply create a condition and add a property mapping for Person.employee with the condition:

```
Condition<?, ?> empIdIsNotZero = new Condition<PersonDTO, Employee>() {
  public boolean applies(MappingContext<PersonDTO, Employee> context) {
    return context.getSource().getEmployeeId() != 0;
  }
};

modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<PersonDTO, Person>() {
  protected void configure() {
    when(empIdIsNotZero).map(source).setEmployee(null);
  }
});
```

When the `empIdIsNotZero` condition applies, mapping will occur as normal. Otherwise mapping will be skipped and `Person.employee` will be set to null.

Check out the ModelMapper site for more docs and examples:

http://modelmapper.org

Comment: You must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers.